# Error running grunt

Tags: sass, gruntjs

When I run the command `sass -v` it appears installed Sass 3.4.22 (Selective Steve)

Then when I already have grunt installed and run grunt in a project that has  grunt I get this

Loading "sass.js" tasks...ERROR

> Error: `libsass` bindings not found. Try reinstalling `node-sass`?
>   Warning: Task "sass" not found. Use `--force` to continue.
>
> Aborted due to warnings.

Comment: What happens when you try to reinstall `node-sass`?

Comment: I get the same error after reinstalling node-sass, Loading "sass.js" tasks...ERROR
>> Error: `libsass` bindings not found. Try reinstalling `node-sass`?
 but I can run grunt serve  and the site runs locally well

Comment: You can try using `grunt-contrib-compass`

Answer (score 5):

You may need: https://github.com/sass/node-sass

```
npm install node-sass
```

`Sass` and `node-sass` are different.

To check your `node-sass` version, open your terminal and type `npm node-sass -v`

Comment: `npm node-sass -v` will list the version of `npm` not the version the `node-sass`. `npm list node-sass` is the correct command to list the down package and its versions

Answer (score 1):

in grunt you need `grunt-sass` or `grunt-contrib-sass`.

`grunt-contrib-sass` need `ruby`.

`grunt-sass` need `node-sass`.

seems link you use `grunt-sass`

node-sass need rebuild by c++ compiler in local computer.
In fact, it will create a binary in `node_modules/node-sass/vendor`.
all binaries is here https://github.com/sass/node-sass-binaries/

Answer (score 0):

To solve: "Task "sass" not found. Use --force to continue."
I did it and WORKED:

```
rm -rf package-lock.json
rm -rf node_modules

npm cache clean --force
npm i grunt-contrib-sass
npm i
grunt
```

;)